# Spring-data-redis RedisMessageListenerContainer seems to have race conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-data-redis

The `lazyListen()` method sets the `listening` flag to true, then starts a Thread to run the SubscriptionTask. Calls to `addMessageListener()` then use the same JedisConnection to subscribe to further topics. But there is no guard on the SubscriptionTask startup process, a call to `addMessageListener()` may arrive before that process is complete, so the subscription may be lost entirely or both threads may write to the same output stream at the same time, so Redis is sent a corrupted command.

There is a similar issue when the task is shutdown after all topics have been unsubscribed. It is possible for a new subscribe command to be sent on the connection before it is returned to the pool. If that connection is then used for non-subscription commands, an error occurs.

The problem can be alleviated by subscribing to a topic and waiting until the subscription task is fully established before allowing further connections, and never unsubscribing from it. But even then it may still occur if the task is shut down because an exception is thrown, so a new SubscriptionTask is created next time a topic is subscribed to.

Comment: Would you mind opening an issue in the [bug tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS). Preferably providing some code to repoduce the problem you're facing. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I didn't find that before. Submitted  DATAREDIS-389: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-389

Comment: already saw that one - we'll check that - thanks for the testcase!